Adding an embedded font to a datagridview
I want to put a custom font to a datagridview but it is not applied, it only applies to other elements such as labels.
I originally tried this and it worked as expected.
fontCollection.AddFontFile("./Resources/Circulitos.ttf");
But then I wanted to try with an embedded file and the font is not displayed correctly in the datagridview, however it is displayed correctly in a label that I have for testing.
This is the code I have:
program.cs
internal static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>

    static private List<PrivateFontCollection> _fontCollections;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        // To customize application configuration such as set high DPI settings or default font,
        // see https://aka.ms/applicationconfiguration.
        ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true);
        Application.ApplicationExit += delegate {
            if (_fontCollections != null)
            {
                foreach (var fc in _fontCollections) if (fc != null) fc.Dispose();
                _fontCollections = null;
            }
        };
        Application.Run(new Main());
    }
    static public Font GetCustomFont(byte[] fontData, float size, FontStyle style)
    {
        if (_fontCollections == null) _fontCollections = new List<PrivateFontCollection>();
        PrivateFontCollection fontCol = new PrivateFontCollection();
        IntPtr fontPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontData.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(fontData, 0, fontPtr, fontData.Length);
        fontCol.AddMemoryFont(fontPtr, fontData.Length);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(fontPtr);
        _fontCollections.Add(fontCol);
        return new Font(fontCol.Families[0], size, style);
    }
}

Main.cs
public partial class Main : Form
{  
    private PrivateFontCollection fontCollection;
    private Font gf;

    public Main()
    {
        gf = Program.GetCustomFont(Properties.Resources.Circulitos, 10, FontStyle.Regular);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void circulitos(int index, bool update)
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
        dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font = gf;
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = gf;
        dataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = gf;
        dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[1];
            try
            {
                cell.Style.Font = gf;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error fontCollection");
            }
            label5.Font = gf;
        }
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
        dataGridView1.Invalidate();
    }  
}

What can I do to make the font apply to the cells of a datagridview and not just to the labels?
Thanks for your time

Read the notes here: How to properly render an embedded Font?. Check out Point 1, then the ▶ paragraph (then try CellPainting -> FormattedValue)

Main.cs
private void DataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 1 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), customFont, Brushes.Black, e.CellBounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.Border);
    }
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
